# Move CVS repository without rechecking out in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

We are migrating from a Server 2000 machine to a Server 2008.  I have already found great instructions for packing up my repository and moving it to the new machine.

My development tool is Eclipse.  My goal is to not remove all of my projects and check them all back out.  That will be a huge pain.

What is the easiest way to point Eclipse over to the new server without removing my existing projects?

The hard method looks to be running some kind of a script that edits about 9 billion CVS\Root files and updates the ip address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the repo settings within Eclipse from the CVS Repositories perspective. Right-click on your repository definitions, change the settings to the new server.

When you save the settings, Eclipse will ask you to confirm that you're changing the server, and then it will update all the required metatdata files.